# How can I call python code from the C++ extension (a .pyd file)

Tags: c++, python, python-c-api

Suppose I have a python module compiled from C++ called Foo (Foo.pyd). Can I call python from the .pyd module? Is it going to use the same interpreter that is running Foo.pyd, or it runs another interpreter?

Assuming I do not use boost python or swig, i.e., only native Python-C API is available.

Comment: Can you be more specific by what you mean by "call python"?  Normally the Python interpreter is initialized by Py_Initialize().  Since you're talking about an extension, you won't be doing that, you will only need to use the Python C-API to do calls.

Comment: @Nick "Call Python " I mean call python code, import some module and execute some function in Python. If I do not do Py_Initialize(), the environment seen by C++ code in Foo (e.g., PYTHONPATH, global dictionary) is the same as the outer level python interpreter (which imported Foo), right?